# "Further the goal": is this use correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, vocabulary

Does the word "Further" fit naturally in the following sentence?

"The modern thinkers believe that by attracting the young generation towards museums, the management furthers the fundamental goal of the museums which is to educate the masses about their history."

Here I want to say that the goal of the museums is to educate the masses, and that the management can get closer to reaching this goal by attracting the young generation.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22further%20the%20goal%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en)  shows a number of hits for the phrase...

Comment: You further a *cause*, typically. Furthering a goal would imply moving a goal farther (further from where it is now). Think alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to **further**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/75716?rskey=WAfJca&result=5&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> 1. transitive. To help forward, assist (usually things; less frequently †persons); to promote, favour (an action or movement). Cf.
>      farther v.   †Also to further forth, on.

As in:

> 1869   J. E. T. Rogers in A. Smith Inq. Wealth Nations:   The
>   necessity of furthering a general system of school training.

and your question, modified with this citation in mind:

*"The modern thinkers believe that by attracting the young generation towards museums, the management **helps forward** the fundamental goal of the museums which is to educate the masses about their history."*

MY sense is this fits nicely and correctly.

Answer (score 2):

"Further your goals" is a common saying. Here are some examples of "further your goals" as written on WikiHow and the New York Times:

https://ludwig.guru/s/to+further+your+goals

Answer (score -1):

Higher as a verb. “ I need to higher a goal” the goal is a numeric value that is a numeric value” can I say “I set the goal higher” or “I am highering your goal from 1kg to 2kg.”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).